# Create Azure AD B2C custom policies and applications using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to create custom B2C policies and B2C applications in Azure AD B2C. I have referred to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) and it is working perfectly for me.

My problem is that I have to do all the steps under **Identity Experience Framework**, as well as the steps for creating a new application for every new tenant in which I have to use B2C features. After going through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration), I found this

> Applications created from the Azure AD B2C blade in the Azure portal
>   must be managed from the same location. If you edit the B2C
>   applications using PowerShell or another portal, they become
>   unsupported and will not work with Azure AD B2C.

but I am not able to infer much regarding custom policies from it.

**I wanted to know if I can use an automated way such as a powershell script to achieve my purpose of creating custom B2C policies as well as create B2C applications.**

Comment: Another documentation [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%202.md) says that these features are only available in AAD B2C Premium, but I guess the feature of **Identity Experience Framework** is newer than the documentation.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252795/4167200

Comment: Its possible to create Custom policies via Power Shell now
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344368/upload-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-via-powershell

Comment: If you use Azure Pipelines you might want to take a look at: https://blog.darkloop.com/post/b2c-release-tools-for-azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to manage B2C policies programmatically. That feature is currently under development, but please vote for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20342455-programmatically-manage-b2c-policies) so that we can let you know when it is available for preview. The feature request for programmatic app mgmt is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19975480-programmatically-register-b2c-applications).

Comment: Has this status changed since?

Answer (score 0):

Since B2C Custom Policies went GA, it is now possible to create custom policies using PowerShell.

See my answer here: [Recommended way to automate deplyoment of Azure AD B2C instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252795/4167200)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell AzureADPreview 2.0 module to create applications.

Full doc is here: [AzureADPreview 2 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)

I had no success to install this module to **"old"** PowerShell (5.x) so I gave a shot to the 'new' PowerShell 7 (Core). The only issue with PowerShell 7 and AzureAD module is that `Connect-AzureAD` uses a cryptographic function which is not in .NET Core, so you *must* import the AzureADPreview module using the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` option.

Here is a sample, works with PowerShell 7:

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview
Import-Module AzureADPreview -UseWindowsPowerShell
$tenantId = "yourb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com"

# Note: this will interactively ask your credentials. 
#       If you want to run this unattended, use the -Credential parameter with a PSCredential object with a SecureString
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId

# ready to go 

#list your all apps    
Get-AzureADApplication 

# examine one of you app and get ideas 
$application = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId af46a788-8e55-4301-b2df-xxxxxxxxx 

# create and application
$applicationName = "yourappname"
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName -PublicClient $true etc
```