# Upload Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Via Powershell

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How can I upload [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) via power shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD B2C now supports PowerShell cmdlets

[Azure AD Preview module documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#trust_framework_policy_management)

[See medium blog](https://blog.medium.com/use-power-shell-to-upload-and-download-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-6fd1786057f1)

**Quick Start**

Launch Power Shell and try below commands

```
> Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview 
> Connect-AzureAd -tenantId <yourtenantname> -accountId <yourAlias@contoso.com>
> Get-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy 
> Get-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy -Id B2C_1A_signup_signin -OutputFilePath C:\B2C_1A_signup_signin.xml
> New-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy  -InputFilePath C:\B2C_1A_signup_signin.xml
> Set-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy  -Id B2C_1A_signup_signin -InputFilePath C:\B2C_1A_signup_signin.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant.

Well, you used to be able to if you had an advanced policy with the B2C powershell tools but ever since they moved from B2C to Identity Experience Framework they have disabled it.

I presume when they go back to ARM templates then they will re-enable it.

Answer (score 1):

**Azure AD B2C currently does not support any programmatic policy management, including Graph, PowerShell or ARM templates.**

You can support this ask and keep track of it (i.e. get notified when there's a preview available) for voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Programmatically Manage B2C Policies](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20342455-programmatically-manage-b2c-policies)